# bison in autoconf can not prompt AC_ERROR

Tags: bison, autoconf

My configure.ac is:

```
AC_PREREQ(2.69)
AC_INIT([mkbib], [2.1], [bnrj.rudra@yahoo.com])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.9.6 dist-bzip2 subdir-objects foreign])

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CC

AC_PROG_YACC
#if test x"$YACC" != x"yes"; then
#  AC_MSG_ERROR([Please install bison before installing.])
#fi
AC_PROG_LEX
if test "x$LEX" != xflex; then
  AC_MSG_ERROR([Please install flex before installing.])
fi

AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
GNOME_DOC_INIT 

# Compiling sources with per-target flags requires AM_PROG_CC_C_O
AM_PROG_CC_C_O
AC_PROG_INSTALL

#AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBSOUP, libsoup-2.4 >= 2.26)
AC_SUBST(LIBSOUP_CFLAGS)
AC_SUBST(LIBSOUP_LIBS)

AM_PATH_GTK_3_0([3.4.0],,AC_MSG_ERROR([Gtk+ 3.0.0 or higher required.]))

AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
        Makefile
        help/Makefile
])
AC_OUTPUT
```

The problem is, while running ./configure built from this file, do check
existence of YACC (as bison, when the 3 line following AC_PROG_YACC, it
is showing unary error), but is not exiting once error is detected. As,
the run, it shows:

```
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
.........................
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating help/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

So, how can I make configure.ac to stop for missing bison and do some `AC_MSG_ERROR` rather then creating a Makefile that will not be compiled?

EDIT: @ldav1s, comparing the string "bison -y" is not general, as, AC_PROG_YACC check both bison/byacc. So, I am thinking if I can put the AC_MSG_ERROR when it shows "no".
so looking for something like:

```
AC_PROG_YACC
if test  "x$YACC" = "xno"; then
  AC_MSG_ERROR([Please install bison before installing.])
fi
```

So, I am

Comment: I know that `AC_PROG_YACC` tests for other `yacc` replacement programs.  You said you wanted `bison`.  So I tested for `bison`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tested and checked.  It stops when bison/byacc/yacc not found.

```
AC_PROG_YACC
if test x"$YACC" = "xyacc"; then
  AC_CHECK_PROG([YACC_EXISTS], [yacc], [yes], [no])
  if test x"$YACC_EXISTS" != xyes; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR([[bison/byacc/yacc not found.
          Please install bison]])
  fi
fi
```

This is for the completeness of the thread.

Answer (score 1):

This problem exists because [autoconf sets `LEX` to `':'` if it can't find a lex](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Particular-Programs), as it's assumed that the generated files will be distributed (as is normally the case for tarballs made using `make dist`, but not if e.g. you are generating your tarball directly)

All these other solutions seem to assume that `$YACC` is `'yacc'` if it's present.  Perhaps a more general solution:

```
AC_PROG_YACC
AC_PATH_PROG(YACC_INST, $YACC)
if test -z "$YACC_INST"; then
   AC_MSG_ERROR([yacc not found])
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

By fixing the commented out code, and adding a little more code:

```
my_YACC=$YACC
AC_PROG_YACC
if test -z "$my_YACC" -a x"$YACC" = x"yacc"; then
  AC_MSG_ERROR([Please install bison/byacc before installing.])
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

ah....sorry! this is solved.

```
AC_PROG_YACC
if test  "x$YACC" = "xno"; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Please install bison before installing.])
fi
```

Comment: -1: won't work.  `AC_PROG_YACC` sets `YACC` to `yacc` if tests for bison/byacc fail.

Comment: true; and probably thats not problematic; configure will show error only when NO flavour of YACC is available.
What is your reason/expectation for configure.ac to do?

Comment: `YACC` will never be set to `no` (unless the user sets it).